# "Everybody Loves Somebody Sometime" in predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

For an assignment, I am supposed to write out all of the logical formulas into the song title "Everybody Loves Somebody Sometime" in predicate logic - Does this look right?

∀p∃t∃q.Loves(p,q,t) - “Everybody Loves Somebody Sometime”

∃p∃q∃t.Loves(p,q,t) - “Somebody loves Somebody Sometimes”

∃p∀t∀q.Loves(p,q,t) - “Somebody loves Everybody All the Time”

∀p∃q∀t.Loves(p,q,t) - “Everybody Loves Somebody All the Time”

Comment: What are $p,q,t$? What is their domain?

Comment: Loves(p, q, t) means that p loves q at time instant t.

Comment: looks fine. Other than that you forgot $\forall$ at 3rd formula.

Comment: How would you write the negation of the latter 2 - ∃p∀t∀q.Loves(p,q,t) and ∀p∃q∀t.Loves(p,q,t) and translate them into English?

Comment: English will sometimes be ambiguous where the logic notation isn't. "Everybody loves somebody sometimes" could mean $\forall p \exists q \exists t . \mathrm{Loves}(p,q,t)$ or $\exists t \forall p \exists q . \mathrm{Loves}(p,q,t)$ or $\exists q \exists t \forall p . \mathrm{Loves}(p,q,t)$ or other variations, but the song probably intends the first.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this assigned in some logic module offered by the PHIL department, or? I'm just wondering whether the learning point is that natural language is, well, not a logical language, or if such assignments are actually meant in earnest.

Comment: $∃p∀t∀q\;L(p,q,t)$ is negated as $∀p∃q∃t\;¬L(p,q,t),$ whose unambiguous translation is "for each person, there exists a time such that it is false that they love someone at that time."